# Optimize absolute value $\min |x| + |y|$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

How do you convert $\min |x| + |y|$ to a linear program?

Is this method correct?

$$\min w + z$$
$$w >= x$$
$$w >= -x$$
$$z >= y$$
$$z >= -y$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct linearization. An alternative approach introduces two nonnegative values and one equality constraint for each absolute value.  See [this post](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/114/how-to-minimize-an-absolute-value-in-the-objective-of-an-lp) for both approaches.